# As a contract owner, how do I remove the ethers from the contract address automatically to my wallet?

Tags: smart-contract-wallets

As a contract owner, how do I remove the ethers from the contract address automatically to my wallet?Can I have a function that when the contract receives the ethers from the costumer, it automatically sends the ethers to the owner wallet address?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to forward ether from receive function to a wallet of your choice.

```
address owner;

receive() external payable {
    payable(owner).transfer(msg.amount);
}
```

Just be aware that

- When invoked from another contract `receive` function has a maximum gas stipend of 2300 gas so transfer will fail. It will work without issues if ether is sent from a non-contract account.
- A contract can receive ether without invoking its receive function, for example by being the recipient of self destructing contract.
- If owner is a contract it has to have a payable receive or fallback function.

The alternative is to have a withdraw function

```
function withdraw() onlyOwner {
    payable(owner).transfer(address(this).balance);
}
```